# How do I run chromedriver free of any extensions?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

How do I set chromedriver to run without any extensions via Capybara env.rb?

Here is my env.rb

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'rspec'
require 'selenium/webdriver'
#require 'capybara/rails'

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome #chrome|firefox
caps.version = "8"
caps.platform = :WINDOWS

Capybara.server_port = 3001
Capybara.app_host = "http://www.google.com"
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    :browser => :chrome #chrome|firefox
    #,
    #:url => "localhost:4444/wd/hub",
    #:desired_capabilities => caps
    )
end
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Comment: What extensions are running as it is currently configured?  I ask because when you run $driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox I don't think it runs without any extensions that are normally installed on the host machine.  Although my example is just using the 'selenium/webdriver' Gem.

Comment: look again.  It's .chrome and  the options are commented

Comment: I understood that you are using chrome.  What I don't understand is if you have commented out what you don't want to run, what is your problem?  What exactly is it doing that you don't want it to do?

Comment: At some point I added an extension by conduit; InternetHelper 1.5.  It is off my normal chrome, but keeps installing onto chromedriver.  I wish it not to, as it screws with capybara.

Comment: I've just registered chrome as `Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)` and it runned without any extensions at my computer. I don't know why it runs with extensions at yourth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer I think is what Andrey Botalov said.

In my case the problem is that I installed a viral software called Conduit.  While posing as legitimate software, it is nearly impossible to remove without some sort of anti-virus.

What was happening is in each instance of lauching chromedriver to run a test, conduit would load NewTabAPI.js onto the new chromdriver. This in turn launched a crappy toolbar. In my case InternetHelper1.5.

At the time of kill NewTabAPI.js had multiple copies sitting in the \Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_directory_....

Removing these killed the virus, but I found a number of conduit directories sitting about that I felt prudent to remove as well.

Anyway,  that's what I needed to do in my case.  In most cases Andrey's comment should do just fine and answers my question.